# Django - How to get all items from a model that has foreign key?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I'm creating two models:
Feedstockformula and formula. This is the code for each one:

FeedstockFormula:

```
from django.db import models

class FeedstockFormulas(models.Model):
    ratio = models.FloatField()
    feedstock = models.OneToOneField("dashboard.Feedstock", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="0")
    formulas = models.ForeignKey("dashboard.Formulas", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

Formula:

```
from django.db import models

class Formulas(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cost = models.FloatField()
    weight = models.FloatField()
```

How can I get all the FeedstockFormulas that is part of a Formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

First get a reference to the formula you want with something like

```
f = Formula.objects.get(name = <formula name>)
```

Then you use it to get the feedstockformulas

```
fsf = FeedstockFormulas.objects.filter(formulas = f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add "related_name" to formulas field in FeedstockFormulas.

Like this:

```
formulas = models.ForeignKey("dashboard.Formulas", related_name="feed_stock_formulas",on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
```

Django use reverse relation on ForeignKey, you can access all FeedstockFormulas that is part of a Formula by writing this:

```
Formulas.feed_stock_formulas
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `FeedstockFormulas` via the **`related_name`** of your `formulas` field, which defaults to `feedstockformulas_set` in your case.

For example:

```
formula = Formulas.objects.first()
print(formula.feedstockformulas_set.all().feedstock)
```